# Medieval term for sister and brother in-law

Tags: single-word-requests, archaicisms

Is there a medieval term for sister/brother-in-law? The only example I could find was in GRR Martin's A Song of Ice and Fire series where he uses the terms *goodsister* and *goodbrother*. Are those rooted in actual medieval terms for in-laws? Were the in-laws even addressed as members of family with specific words? (I've read somewhere that before 19th century the in-laws were used instead of step-mother/father/etc., so they could not be used for the other relation or would be very confusing).

Comment: In answer to your comment in brackets, you may have it the wrong way round. A stepmother used to be called a mother-in-law (e.g. in Dickens' _Pickwick Papers_), presumably because the relationship was created by a marriage, though in this case one's father's not one's own.

Comment: By the way, the term *goodsister* is probably a loan translation from French *belle-soeur*, "sister in law". Dutch borrowed the same word (with the same meaning) as *schoonzuster*. *Belle = schoon* = "beautiful, nice". Oddly, *bonne-soeur* ("good sister") is used for nuns. So perhaps the English translation is based on an older use of *bonne-soeur*, or Englishmen at the time confused *belle-soeur* with *bonne-soeur*.

Comment: "sister's husband" etc also seem common.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, they have been called in laws for a while. Here are its earliest examples of each:

- > [We] schul be samen hole frendes, lelli breþeren in lawe.
  >   <sub>[The romance of William of Palerne](https://books.google.com/books?id=2FU6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA151), a1375</sub>
- > Syster yn lawe, as howsolde syster [?a1475 Winch. husbandis syster], or wyfys syster, glos.
  >   [...]
  >   Syster yn lawe, broders wyyf, *fratrissa*.
  >   <sub>[Promptorium parvulorum sive clericorum](https://books.google.com/books?id=KPgUAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA457&lpg=PA457&dq=%22Syster+yn+lawe,+as+howsolde+syster%22), 1440</sub>

---

Later, in the [1530 Tyndale Bible](https://books.google.com/books?id=ySMXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA600&dq=%22Yf+the+man+will+not+take+his%22) (a little too late for it to be considered medieval) shortened versions of these terms, **sister law** and **brother law**, were used (again, the earliest examples I could find in the OED):

> Yf the man will not take his systerlawe, then let her goo to the gate vnto the elders and saye: My brotherlawe..will not marie me.

---

Confusingly enough, sometimes they are simply referred to as **brother** and **sister** according to the OED:

- > No man..miȝt telle þe ioye þat þe bold breþeren..made, william & alphouns.
  >   <sub>[The romance of William of Palerne](https://books.google.com/books?id=2FU6AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA151#v=onepage&q=%22william%20%26%20alphouns%22), a1375</sub>
- > Suster..With al thauys, heer of my perlement.
  >   <sub>[Canterbury Tales](https://books.google.com/books?id=QiGazUrpnusC&pg=PA157&dq=%22With+al+thauys%22), c1405</sub>

---

In addition, **good brother** and **good sister** were used, but mainly in Scottish English. The OED's earliest respective citations are:

- > Iames steward, that ledar was Eftir his gud brother disses.
  >   <sub>[The Bruce](https://books.google.com/books?id=rE1irGI8-YEC&pg=PA473&lpg=PA473&dq=%22his+gud+brother+disses%22), 1375</sub>
- > That his gud systyr the Quenys grace be nocht therby mynyst in hyr autorite.
  >    <sub>*Douglas Book*, 1515</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Brother-in-law in English is *tacor* and sister-in-law is *doomsister*. Father-in-law is *swēor* and mother-in-law is *sweġer*.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well, the Normans conquered England, so a lot of "foreign" words have entered English from Old French. But sister-in-law and brother-in-law are both made of Anglo-Saxon words.

Comment: No, they are a combination of Old English and Old Norse. Law is Old Norse, doom is the same in Old English. If sister-in-law and brother-in-law were all English they would be something like doombrother (tacor) and doomsister.